# Select query not printing all of the items

Tags: sql, sqlite

When running

```
SELECT 
s.id space_id
,s.name space_name
,i.name item_name
,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.category) attribute_names
FROM spaces s
INNER JOIN spaceItemAssociations sia ON sia.space_id = s.id
INNER JOIN items i ON i.id = sia.item_id
INNER JOIN itemAssociations ia ON ia.items_id = i.id
INNER JOIN itemAttributes a ON ia.itemAttributes_id = a.id
WHERE s.id = 1
```

on this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9eecb7/8122) I get only one row instead of four.

Expected:

- 4 rows with the objects belonging to this space and their attributes

Actual:

- 1 row

Is it my select that is wrong?

Comment: Your query *should* be returning an error.  It is an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` but has unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because an aggregate function (`GROUP_CONCAT`) is present, this is an aggregate query - but because no `GROUP BY` is present, it aggregates over the entire result set, leaving you with a single result row.

If you want distinct categories for each item (each group of rows corresponding to the same item), rather than distinct categories across all items, add a `GROUP BY i.id` or similar.

[Reference](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset)

Answer (score 0):

When you tried to `GROUP_CONCAT` rows by categories, you don't see that you only have `attribute2` for these 4 rows. Normal behavior is to show only 1 row because of `GROUP_CONCAT` clause.

Check now on my [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/bf997/4) when I commented out `GROUP_CONCAT` that query return all 4 rows.

```
SELECT 
s.id space_id
,s.name space_name
,i.name item_name
, a.category
--,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.category) attribute_names
FROM spaces s
INNER JOIN spaceItemAssociations sia ON sia.space_id = s.id
INNER JOIN items i ON i.id = sia.item_id
INNER JOIN itemAssociations ia ON ia.items_id = i.id
INNER JOIN itemAttributes a ON ia.itemAttributes_id = a.id
WHERE s.id = 1
```